# Generic save method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, generics, asp.net-mvc-4

In my generic repository I need to write generic Save method which will edit existed or add new entity depending on id.

```
public void Save<T>(T entity) where T : TEntity, IKeyId
{
    if (ObjectSet.Any(r => (r as IKeyId).KeyId == entity.KeyId))
    {
        Edit(entity);
    }
    else
    {
        Add(entity);
    }
}
```

But Linq generate exception when I try do `Any( r=> (r as IKeyId)...`. 
*The 'TypeAs' expression with an input of type 'MyProg.DAL.Appeal' and a check of type 'Claimstrak.DAL.Interfaces.IKeyId' is not supported. Only entity types and complex types are supported in LINQ to Entities queries.*

How to write it correct?

Comment: Well, the exception is clear, you can't use interfaces casting in linq to entities... Now, to find a solution, a little bit more code (to understand how and why do you use ObjectSet, for example) would be usefull.

Comment: You know EF will tell you if an entity is new or modified or deleted.

Comment: I know. Unforchenatly my key (id) in that table is not own id. Column is reference to another table and is not identity.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the truth is that you dont need to use the ObjectSet, you can just use DbContext to do this, in a much more easy way.

Bu, i would tell that this is not a good pattern to use, to call a Save() in a repository. I would recomend that you consider the .SaveSession() of the Context only after all was done, this way you can do a lot of things befose making a round trip to te database.

So, you should make a method like this, but not call the SaveChanges(), instead of a Save() method, to a UpdateOrInsert() and them, after all is done you call the .Save()

But i will give the examplefollowing your request (but i dont recommend, i recommend you separate IUnitOfWork from IRepository)

See how the code is very simple:

```
    interface IKeyId
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }

    DbContext context = new YourContext();

    public bool Save<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class, IKeyId
    {
        return (entity.Id == 0) ? Add<TEntity>(entity) : Edit<TEntity>(entity);
    }

    public bool Edit<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class, IKeyId
    {
        var set = context.Set<TEntity>();
        set.Attach(entity);
        return true;
    }

    public bool Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class, IKeyId
    {
        var set = context.Set<TEntity>();
        set.Add(entity);
        return true;
    }
```

I use a similar approach im my repositories, i have changed the T4 (.tt file) that generates the POCO classes from my database to excplicitly implement some interfaces that i have, such as IAuditable, IValidatable and other, so the T4 automaticaly implement those interfaces in the classes.