# .net core generic save method/class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm working with a .net core 2.0 / EF core project, where I'm trying to abstract my save method.

Right now my save methods looks as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(AbJob abJob)
{
    var obj = abJob;
    var addObj = _context.AbJobs;
    var addObjVersion = _context.AbJobVersions;
    var objVersion = new AbJobVersion();

    // loads of generic transactions and save stuff here

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I want to change this to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(AbJob abJob)
{
    var obj = abJob;
    var addObj = _context.AbJobs;
    var addObjVersion = _context.AbJobVersions;
    var objVersion = new AbJobVersion();

    GenericSave(obj, addObj, addObjVersion, objVersion);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

But I'm pretty clueless (overall novice) when it comes to abstraction.

My best guess is to create a class called something like GenericHelpers.cs with a method roughly as follows:

```
public bool GenericSave(obj, addObj, addObjVersion, objVersion)
{
    // loads of generic transactions and save stuff here
    return true;
}
```

My guess is that I'll be able to tie this togehter as soon as I know which type of method to use and how to pass this kind of objects to it.

I hope you can help.

Comment: EF already has a generic save method: `SaveChanges`. For the rest, *in fact* all business logic that's related to persisted entities is about setting the correct state of entity objects. That's too specific per use case to try and create a generic method for it.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean.

I have the exact same methodology across all classes. Eg. client:

Classes: Client, ClientVersion //
Tables: Clients, ClientVersions //

when creating/editing a client i test if it exist in Clients, then save accordingly to Clients, then save a copy to ClientVersions, then update Clients with the respective ClientVersion Id in order to create a cross table audit trail. All this is wrapped in one transaction.

I have found this, but can't get started:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562673/generic-save-method